# making separate lists of materials with different material types by creating separate lists from array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have some material types which I got from variable "exactSizedTypesDetected" used below which is an array containing other arrays (the materials names are in separate arrays). There is a list of materials in the variable "exactSizedMaterialsData" same in the form of array containing arrays of material. What my goal was to seperate materials in terms of material types and store them in separate variables so I made variables with names exacSizedList(1-100). The criteria from which I want to detect which material type a material is belonging is that it checks the second value in the array and matches it which I achieved using "forEach(function(a) { if (a[1] ==exactSizedTypesDetected[i-1])".

Below is the code I used but its not working for me when I do logger.log(). My goal is simply that I want to create separate lists automatically which contains material types ie single list for each material type and be saved as seperate array variable automatically without me doing manually.

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

```
function seperateExactSized() {
      // create variables
      var exacSizedList1,exacSizedList2,exacSizedList3,exacSizedList4,exacSizedList5,
          exacSizedList6,exacSizedList7,exacSizedList8,exacSizedList9,exacSizedList10,
          exacSizedList11,exacSizedList12,exacSizedList13,exacSizedList14,exacSizedList15,
          exacSizedList16,exacSizedList17,exacSizedList18,exacSizedList19,exacSizedList10,
          exacSizedList21,exacSizedList22,exacSizedList23,exacSizedList24,exacSizedList25,
          exacSizedList26,exacSizedList27,exacSizedList28,exacSizedList29,exacSizedList30,
          exacSizedList31,exacSizedList32,exacSizedList33,exacSizedList34,exacSizedList35,
          exacSizedList36,exacSizedList37,exacSizedList38,exacSizedList39,exacSizedList40,
          exacSizedList41,exacSizedList42,exacSizedList43,exacSizedList44,exacSizedList45,
          exacSizedList46,exacSizedList47,exacSizedList48,exacSizedList49,exacSizedList50,
          exacSizedList51,exacSizedList52,exacSizedList53,exacSizedList54,exacSizedList55,
          exacSizedList56,exacSizedList57,exacSizedList58,exacSizedList59,exacSizedList60,
          exacSizedList61,exacSizedList62,exacSizedList63,exacSizedList64,exacSizedList65,
          exacSizedList66,exacSizedList67,exacSizedList68,exacSizedList69,exacSizedList70,
          exacSizedList71,exacSizedList72,exacSizedList73,exacSizedList74,exacSizedList75,
          exacSizedList76,exacSizedList77,exacSizedList78,exacSizedList79,exacSizedList80,
          exacSizedList81,exacSizedList82,exacSizedList83,exacSizedList84,exacSizedList85,
          exacSizedList86,exacSizedList87,exacSizedList88,exacSizedList89,exacSizedList90,
          exacSizedList91,exacSizedList92,exacSizedList93,exacSizedList94,exacSizedList95,
          exacSizedList96,exacSizedList97,exacSizedList98,exacSizedList99,exacSizedList100 =[];

      // set variables dynamically
      for(var i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        eval("exacSizedList"+[i] + " = " + i);
        eval("exacSizedList"+[i-1] + ".push(a)");
        exactSizedMaterialsData.forEach(function(a) { if (a[1] ==exactSizedTypesDetected[i-1])  
          eval("exacSizedList"+[i] + ".push(a)"); });
        Logger.log(eval("exacSizedList"+[i] + ".push(a)"));
        Logger.log(eval("exacSizedList"+[i] ));
       }
      }
```

Comment: I think you need to change your unmaintainable nightmare to a much simpler version, using an object with keys. `const exactSizes = {};` This approach lets you have an arbitrary number of lists. Within your loop, you simply need to check if that key has been initialized yet: `if (! exactSizes[key]) exactSizes[key] = [];` and then you can add the appropriate element to that key. (Note that your current code only initialized the last variable you declared.)

Answer (score 0):

There are many questions about your function.  For example, where are exactSizedTypesDetected & exactSizedMaterialsData defined?  i is undefined in your forEach function. For your eval to execute "a" needs to be defined and why you do it outside the forEach and inside the forEach function?  If the first eval is executed your exacSizedListi becomes an integer instead of an array. I'm assuming exactSizedTypesDetected has 100 values but if there is no matching value in exactSizedMaterialsData that sub array will be empty.  And so ultimately you could have an unsymmetrical array.  You would not be able to use setValues() in Google Sheets.

I'm not sure if this does everything you intended but this is how I would do it.

```
function seperateExactSized() {
  try {
    var exacSizedList = [];
    for( var i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
      exacSizedList.push([]);
    }
    for( var i=0; i<exactSizedMaterialsData.length; i++ ) {
      for( var j=0; j<100; j++ ) {
        // Where are exactSizedTypesDetected & exactSizedMaterialsData defined?
        if( exactSizedTypesDetected[j] === exactSizedMaterialsData[i][1] ) {
          exacSizedList[j].push(exactSizedMaterialsData[i]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```